# Subtract HOURS from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (DB2)

Tags: db2

I need to substract 4 hours from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DB2, my query in SQL DEVELOPER is correct because I can see the registers I need to see, but when I do the query in Eclipse have some problem and I don't know which is. This is the query I need to do:

```
"SELECT yerror, COUNT(yerror) AS CantidadErrores FROM kexg.VD03154 WHERE tumod BETWEEN (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 4 HOUR) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP GROUP BY yerror;";
```

This query returns me an error but if I put ***24 HOUR*** is correct. Also is correct if I put ***5 DAYS*** for example.

I have try to subtract ***04* HOUR,** and it's wrong also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the *error code* ?  Never write "returns me an error", instead write exactly what the full error code and error message is.  Your query is syntactically  OK if the column datatype of kexg.VD03154.tumod is TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works beautifully for me on DB2 for z/OS:

```
select current timestamp as rightnow,
       current timestamp - 4 hours 
  from sysibm.sysdummy1 
; 

RIGHTNOW                    COL1                      
--------------------------  --------------------------
2020-02-27-08.16.55.142456  2020-02-27-04.16.55.142456
```